# Как установить OpenSSL на Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, openssl

Как установить OpenSSL на Windows 10 ? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/

Answer (score 0):

на сайте OpenSSL в разделе community есть ссылка на binary distributions.
на wiki:

[OpenSSL Binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries)

там можно перейти на страницы третьих фирм сделавших официальные версии.